# Common C# classes are not visible in UWP project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm trying to create a small cross-platform app using Visual Studio / Xamarin. From the solution template I've got 4 sections:

- Common classes
- .Android
- .iOS
- .UWP

Now I create a new class / new interface in Common section, make them public and assume they should be visible in platform projects, especially UWP.

But classes are not recognized. I have no idea why ;/

Comment: do you have a reference in your UWP to your common project?

Comment: Bingo! I assumed they were already referenced from solution template, but this was not the case. Thank you!

Comment: @Jason Your comment seemed to resolve the OP's issue, so you should consider posting it as an answer to this question and getting them to accept it.